# Как победить ограницения в сетевых подключениях к ПК?

Tags: сеть, доступ, windows-xp

В winXP PRO есть ограничения по подключению к ресурсу. Всего 10 пк могут подключиться.
Кроме как ковыряния в реестре для отключения пустых сеансов, я так понимаю выхода нет?И решить проблему можно только переход на Win2003 Server?
Юзеров у меня 20-30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Half-open limit fix (patch) для Windows](http://half-open.com/home_ru.htm) Вам в помощь...

Вторая ссыль в [известной поисковой системе](https://www.google.by/search?q=%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9+xp&oq=%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9+xp&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.267j0j9&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)...

**UPD** Он сам за вас поковыряет реестр. После некоторых обновлений может потребоваться повторный запуск.

Comment: Да, именно так. В свое время аналогичным образом победил это ограничение.   Сейчас для меня лучший вариант - установить Linux-систему в виде сервера (но в этом случае следует повнимательнее отнестись к потребностям юзеров - т.е. какие ресурсы нужно разделять для них. Просто файл-сервер, принт-сервер или, например, сервер 1С - в принципе, все реализуемо). Исходя из того, что у Вас сервером служит ХРюша (т.е. у Вас скорее всего просто файл-сервер) - любой дистрибутив Linux обеспечит Вам необходимые средства.

Comment: Поддержу *nix-овый выбор! Со своей стороны рекомендовал бы Ubuntu, как, _на мой взгляд_, наиболее дружественную :)ЗЫ Про 1С под nix-ами -- читал, что реализуемо, но не без плясок народов крайнего севера. Реализовать не решился, по крайней мере - пока...

Comment: @Zerglyn  Спасибо!  Буду пробовать.  P.S. О, как! хитрый файлик tcpip.sys, просто так не ковырнёшь.

Comment: да нет - элементарно, Ватсон! Грузимся под live-linux`ом и тупо меняем файл (прежний обязательно сохранить как tcpip-sys.bak)